# In R, how can I grab the penultimate row from a data frame for each ID when IDs are non-unique?

Tags: r, dataframe, bigdata

I have data with the following format. There is a non-unique ID, the number of times it's shown up, and more data.

I want to add the pen-ultimate row for each ID to a new table, IE a2, and b4.

What are a couple methods for accomplishing this?

```
ID  #   data
a   1   ...
a   2   ...
a   3   ...

b   1   ...
b   2   ...
b   3   ...
b   4   ...
b   5   ...
...
```

Comment: (the duplicate has answers via base R (`tapply`) and `data.table`.  The `plyr` answer below rounds out the possibilities.)

Comment: Since you also tagged big data, you might want to utilize the ``data.table`` package.  ``mydata <- data.table(mydata);mydata2 <- mydata[,list(penult=valueyouwant[.N-1]),by="ID];``

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I understand the motivation. You fail to include a full example. And the example you use has column names are are invalid in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to @Ben's answer and those in the duplicate answer, you could use `dplyr` to achieve this:

```
df %.%                 #your data.frame
 group_by(ID) %.% 
 mutate(count = 1:n()) %.% 
 filter(count %in% max(c(count-1,1))) %.%   #if each ID occures more than 1 time, you can simplify this to filter(count %in% max(count-1)) %.%
 select(-count)
```

This can also be written in a single line:

```
df %.% group_by(ID) %.% mutate(count = 1:n()) %.% filter(count %in% max(c(count-1,1))) %.% select(-count)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `plyr::ddply`:

```
penult <- function(x) head(tail(x,2),1))
ddply(mydata,"ID",penult)
```

Somewhat to my surprise this actually works fine in the edge case (only one row per ID), because `tail(x,2)` returns a single row in that case.

Answer (score 0):

```
 mydata[ tapply( rownames(mydata), mydata$ID, function(n) n[ min(1, length(n)-1 ] ) ), ]
```

No testing in absence of a valid example. The edge case of a single row for an ID was not considered in your problem formulation so I decided to use the solitary row in that situation.